# Is the last day of a thai visa included?

Tags: visas, thailand

I have a plane ticket for thailand the 16th of September. (Landing will be on the 17th of September)

if I have a tourist visa it should be 60 days, so I will be admitted until 16th of November.

Can I take a plane ticket to another country the 16th of November ? Or should I leave before the 16th of November ?

And yes... this day is important for me unfortunately...

Comment: Doesn’t that make 61 days already?

Comment: Hmmmm I guess you are right, i was counting the number of days after 17th of september. But is the last day included ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

60 days will take you to **15th November**, but you should plan to leave a day or two earlier to ensure you don't overstay because of unexpected delays. If you need to be in Thailand on 16th, take a later flight in September.

Comment: Yes but I already booked the flight in september...

Comment: But if I land 17th of September, I can take a plane the 15th of November, right ?

Comment: You can leave on or before 15 November 2019.   Or at least you need to pass through departure immigration on 15 November 2019.